# Question about the graphs of marginal effect in interaction terms and its hypothesis test in ggpredict()

Tags: r, data-science, visualization, margin, interaction

I met a problem when trying to visualize the marginal effect of my model.

My code is as follows:

```
fit7am=svyglm(formula=visa~age+male+pregnant+foreigner+fujian+migrant+agent+disadveth+ifoplive+otherpaidtrip+geotravex_oecd+ocpr0+lsal+satsal+educyear+schpc9foreig+lwealthwosqm+like+married+numsib+jobyear+chimin+parret+famtiegravsponsor+conf+offwhite+offm+geotravex_educyear + geotravex_educyear+ age*chimin+ male_chimin+ age_male+ married*age+ married_chimin+ married_male+ parret_numsib+ parret_age+parret_chimin,
             design=survey_design,
             family=binomial(),
             rescale=TRUE)

library(ggeffects)
result <- ggpredict(fit7am, c("age", "chimin"))
hypothesis_test(result)
```

[result for hypothesis_test()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9i7Kb.png)

(chimin here is a binary variable to categorize whether a person has a minor child)

I wonder why the reported contrast (and its p-value) here is different from the coefficient before the age*chimin in my regression model. Shouldn’t the slope difference between group chimin=0 &1 for predicting the probability of getting visa be equivalent to the coefficient before their interaction term in the regression, holding all other variables equal.

Am I understanding this graph and test correctly? Can we still use it for reporting our results?

Comment: Hi Ryan, welcome to Stack Overflow. May I suggest that you post your question over at Cross Validated? We do answer R questions here, but your question seems to be more about interpreting the results of your statistical analysis instead of a programming problem.  If you post there, you will likely have more helpful responses.  Like you did here, you should also post your results there.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the related [vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_comparisons.html), in particular the section with a [short example on glm's](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_comparisons.html#contrasts-and-comparisons-for-glm---logistic-regression-example).

The coefficients from the summary-table are - by default - presented as log-odds, and often transformed to odds ratios. Predicted values are usually presented as *probabilities* (as in your case), and so the results refer to the difference between the predicted probabilities of `visa` for `age` at the different values of `chimin`. This difference (or contrast) is also expressed on the response scale (probabilities), or more precise, as difference of %-points for the different probabilities of `chimin` levels.

The contrasts are presented on the link-scale by default if no categorical focal terms are involved (see also an example in the above mentioned vignette).

Here's a toy example. As you can see, the "slopes" for `age` at different levels of `chimin` are quite similar:

```r
library(ggeffects)
set.seed(1234)
dat <- data.frame(
  visa = rbinom(n = 100, size = 1, prob = 0.35),
  chimin = as.factor(sample(1:2, size = 100, TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))),
  age = rnorm(n = 100, mean = 10, sd = 7)
)

m <- glm(visa ~ age * chimin, data = dat, family = binomial())
pr <- ggpredict(m, c("age", "chimin"))
#> Data were 'prettified'. Consider using `terms="age [all]"` to get smooth
#>   plots.
plot(pr)
```

[image]

When you just print the contrasts without pairwise comparison, you can see this, too. The average slope is almost the same:

```r
hypothesis_test(pr, test = NULL)
#> # Linear trend for age
#> 
#> chimin |     Slope |        95% CI |     p
#> ------------------------------------------
#> 1      | -9.98e-03 | [-0.02, 0.00] | 0.178
#> 2      | -9.45e-03 | [-0.02, 0.00] | 0.140
#> 
#> Slopes are presented as probabilities.
```

Consequently, the difference of these two average slopes is tiny as well.

```r
hypothesis_test(pr)
#> # Linear trend for age
#> 
#> chimin |  Contrast |        95% CI |     p
#> ------------------------------------------
#> 1-2    | -5.30e-04 | [-0.02, 0.02] | 0.957
#> 
#> Contrasts are presented as probabilities.
```

<sup>Created on 2023-08-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>